# Problems exporting SVGs from Sketch 3

Tags: svg, sketch-app

I go to export assets from Sketch as SVG files. I have a few problems...

1. If I select the assets and it automatically slices it, I then save out the SVG file and it gets cut off. [circle icon example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t2r7ndr1c6d7zs9/fwd-arrow-btn-circle-hover.svg)
2. Inserting into code looks crisp on safari but in Firefox and Chrome it looks blurry (only on a non retina desktop).

Anyone have problems like this? I thought it was because the icons are 1px lines but they look fantastic on my screen at 100%. I just don't get it.

Comment: Same problem - circle icons are cut off. Exporting png works fine with these icons, by the way.

Comment: Same problem, exporting as PNG solved it for now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you vectorize all of your strokes when exporting to SVG. This will keep your circle icons from being cut off. There is no need to use a mask.

Follow Layer/Paths/Vectorize Stroke.

Answer (score 1):

So I have the same problem with clipping of icons in exporting svg.

Here is kind of a hack way I played around with that makes the clipping problem go away:

Create a mask layer (of the share you desire) under your icon layer. See screenshot below:

[image]